# Get SOAP request in JAX-WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have a simple JAX-WS client and server.

I want to get the SOAP request sent by client in server side.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's the purpose of the server :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to see the actual soap-message in xml, you can use the apache tool [tcpMon](http://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set java property either on server side or on client side as specified in [documentation](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.8/docs/ch06.html#message-logging). Although [handler](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.8/docs/ch03.html#users-guide-handler) could be an option if you'd need to do something more than just dump SOAP messages. Depending on your environment tcpdump might be most simple solution - no need to restart server, download software etc. actually I prefer it when there's need for such measures.
One peculiar thing to note is that MTOM optimization occurs after handlers execute, so tcpdump would show actual message sent through the wire.